# How to bypass a MCU if it fails?

Tags: microcontroller, signal-processing, bypass

I'm designing a system in which a MCU processes a PWM signal and outputs a slightly modified version of it. As this signal is extremely critical for the application, I'm looking for a way to output the raw input signal if the MCU fails, bypassing it completely. How could I do this?

Comment: How exactly do you picture the bypass to happen? Manually by someone pressing a switch? Automatically by the PCB itself?

Comment: How could you notice if your MCU has failed?

Comment: A SPDT switch??

Comment: So, hey pedrocklein, could you please tell us way more about when, under which circumstances, within which time, on whose authority that bypass would happen? Information about the application and the MCU and the software running on the MCU would help, too, to give you helpful answers. Like this, your question is lacking too much to be answered :( At the **very** least, you need to define what "MCU failed" means: Stuck at the last output state? Stuck at high-impedance output? Outputting random garbage? Something else?

Comment: We need more information for a good answer. But, generally, a watchdog timer that is *external* to the MCU is used as a fail-safe for critical applications. In your case, when the watchdog expires, a mux could be used to switch to the raw signal.

Comment: The 'standard' route for this would be a relay held in by a monostable being triggered by a watchdog timer on the MCU. If the watchdog stops, the relay drops out and routes the signal round the MCU. Relay reliability might be an issue. 'MCU failure' might not always stop the watchdog routine. You've a few details to fill in before you get a solution. How about triplicate the MU and have hardware on the output passing the majority vote?

Comment: Just remember that any "failsafe" circuit is, itself, subject to failure.  It's a good idea to study up on fault-tolerant design (and on all the ways that various clever "fault tolerant" systems have ended up being more fault sensitive than the "unprotected" prototypes they sought to improve on).

Comment: I had to diagnose a problem with a device that operated from a servo pulse, which had a 'failsafe' function in case the MCU died. The signal was bypassed with a 74LVC logic gate, which kept blowing up randomly after the manufacturer made an 'insignificant' change to the circuit. The failsafe circuit caused the device to fail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define what "MCU failing" means. In a generic application, the most likely faults are probably either the firmware going haywire or the part getting shorted/fried/losing solder connection etc, all of these risking MCU hang up.

Normally you'd protect against such through digital logic, by having the MCU repeatedly feed an external watchdog circuit, such as a monostable multivibrator ([example](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/stand_alone_watchdog_timers)) or similar part that needs to be repeatedly refreshed with a signal.

Then let the MCU's transmitted PWM go through a fast-enough switch/mux. As long as the MCU keeps feeding the external watchdog, the external watchdog will enable the MCU PWM output through this switch. Otherwise, it will pick the input PWM and route that one to the output instead.

A design like this could be sufficient even for safety/mission critical purposes, though you might have to walk some extra mile in risk assessment. For example, when this fault happens it might be important to alert about the system having entered this "failsafe/limp home" mode. And high integrity systems may require multiple MCUs supervising each other etc.